# Internet Explorer $.ajax() Won't Load

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am creating a page which loads HTML into a container via an $.ajax() request. This works perfectly under Firefox (long live Firefox!), IE does not load the external content. Here is a snippet of my code, could you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
$.ajax({
  'type' : 'GET',
  'url' : 'page.php',
  'success' : function(data) {
  //If valid data is returned...
    if (data !== '') {
      $('div#form').html(data);
    } else {
      alert('Data way empty!');
    }
  }
});
```

Thank you for your time,
spryno724

Comment: You're using a page that does an AJAX request to itself? I'm not sure I know why you would ever need to do that.

Comment: There is actually a lot more that goes on than the page requesting data from itself. I changed the post to make it a little more clear.

Comment: The code you have posted has no problems in it. It is almost the cononical boilerplate jquery ajax call. I am fairly certain that the problem lies elsewhere in the code. Can you show us all the relevant code?

Comment: How do you check for GET requests? I only know how to do that in Firebug. :S

Comment: Oh... just alert() the "data", checking that...

Comment: Yeah... the data is being fetched, but not put inside of the container. Check my edit for a more complete example

Comment: Ok, I got it. If your interested my post is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally found an answer. I was a problem with IE's ability to insert with jQuery's .html() method. Here is the working code, in both IE and Firefox:

```
$.ajax({
  'type' : 'GET',
  'url' : 'page.php',
  'success' : function(data) {
    $('div#form')[0].innerHTML = data;
  }
});
```

Hope that helps someone,
spryno724

Comment: IE should have no issue unless the HTML you are putting in is invalid.

Comment: It is not a full HTML page (i.e.: no <head>, <body>, <title>, <html> tags), but the HTML being inserted in is valid. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: From jQuery docs: "This method uses the browser's innerHTML property." The only reason this should be different in any way from your original code, is if more than one element was selected, in which case jQuery will try to replace the contents of each one. What you are doing is so commonplace, there is simply no possibility that jQuery could have a problem with it and IE 6 or later. Millions of applications would not work. There must be something else going on with the selector or the query. The fact that this works just means you have worked around a problem, likely temporarily.

Comment: If the HTML being inserted is valid as you say, then I now really am curious. The `.html()` function is supposed to be a feasible archetype of `.innerHTML`, and for the most part, you're basically performing the same thing. I wonder.

Comment: Would you perhaps get the same (invalid) result when you use `.text()` instead of `.html()`? You're not supposed to use `.text()` to insert DOM elements, but just to have a look-see.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the extra comments. I have the returned HTML in the post below.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the missing quote at the start of 'type'.  If you get a character wrong, all the other browsers may tend to gloss over it, but ie will choke.

Comment: It's in my actual code, just forgot to copy it when I moved it to here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the incoming HTML. I don't see anything invalid in there:

```
<form name="register" method="post" id="validate" action="/biomed-ed/users/register.htm?step=true&_=1302494250437">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td width="200" align="right">First name</td>
<td width="600"><div class="glowBox">
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" class="validate[required]" />
<span class="tip" id='{"revert" : "Enter your first name", "empty" : "We need your first name"}'>Enter your first name</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="200" align="right">Last name</td>
<td width="200"><div class="glowBox">
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" class="validate[required]" />
<span class="tip" id='{"revert" : "Enter your last name", "empty" : "We need your last name"}'>Enter your last name</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="200" align="right">Username</td>
<td width="200"><div class="glowBox custom noHide">
<input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" size="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" class="validate[required]" />
<span class="tip" id='{"revert" : "Username must be unique", "empty" : "Please provide a username", "valid" : "This name is avaliable", "invalid" : "Sorry, this name is taken"}'>Username must be unique</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="200" align="right">Password</td>
<td width="200"><div class="glowBox custom">
<input type="password" name="passWord" id="passWord" size="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" class="validate[required]" />
<span class="tip" id='{"revert" : "6 characters or more!", "empty" : "You will need a password", "valid" : "Good password!", "invalid" : "Too short"}'>6 characters or more!</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr class="spacer">
<td width="200"></td>
<td width="200"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="200" align="right">Primary Email Address</td>
<td width="200"><div class="glowBox custom">
<input type="text" name="primaryEmail" id="primaryEmail" size="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" class="validate[required]" />
<span class="tip" id='{"revert" : "Enter your email address", "empty" : "An email is required", "valid" : "Email is valid" ,"invalid" : "Invalid email address"}'>Enter your email address</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="200" align="right">Secondary Email Address</td>
<td width="200"><div class="glowBox custom optional">
<input type="text" name="secondaryEmail" id="secondaryEmail" size="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" class="validate[required]" />
<span class="tip" id='{"revert" : "Enter your email address", "valid" : "Email is valid" ,"invalid" : "Invalid email address"}'>Only if you have one</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="200" align="right">Tertiary Email Address</td>
<td width="200"><div class="glowBox custom optional">
<input type="text" name="tertiaryEmail" id="tertiaryEmail" size="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="true" class="validate[required]" />
<span class="tip" id='{"revert" : "Enter your email address", "valid" : "Email is valid" ,"invalid" : "Invalid email address"}'>Only if you have one</span></div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="200" align="right"></td>
<td width="200">
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next Step"">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```